# Adding external self written code link to own question?

Tags: discussion, questions

About 8 months ago, I asked a question on gamedev:

[Consistent cross platform procedural generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/202475/consistent-cross-platform-procedural-generation)

The discussion there inspired me to write some C and C++ code myself to deal with the issues raised in the question (I couldn't find anything existing that really fit my use case), which I have been successfully using for a while. I just split out into its own public github repo.

My question: would it be appropriate to provide a link to the repo (with an appropriate disclaimer that the question author wrote it)? I think it would be of some value to someone else that came here with a similar problem, and the code is too big to paste directly.

If so, would it be most appropriate to (1) add it as a note to the end of my question that this was the direction I went, or (2) add it as a new answer?

I don't consider this a duplicate of:

[Is it good tone to link your own (open source) projects to support your answer?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/is-it-good-tone-to-link-your-own-open-source-projects-to-support-your-answer)

as in this case it was my question originally. When I asked the question I wasn't expecting that I'd write this code myself (I was expecting "everyone uses <...>" which I'd then go and use too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is it appropriate, but it is encouraged to answer your own question.  However, do not provide a link-only answer.  In addition to the link, provide a summary which can stand alone should the link ever rot.  Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: My main concern was that answering my own question with a link to my own project could be seen as spamming, but that is a very good point - I'll post information that stands alone along with the link, including some sample code.

Comment: I feel like my answer for the linked question holds for this one as well. Since this answer seems to be in the same spirit, I'm upvoting rather than repeating.